# ¿"Diviértete" o "disfruta"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, puerto-rico

Quiero desear que alguien disfrute de un regalo con la frase (en inglés):

> Enjoy!

¿Cuál de estas uso?

- Diviértete
- Disfruta

¿o hay alguna más?

El destinatario es puertorriqueño.

Comment: *¡Espero que te guste [tu regalo]!*

Comment: Y *que la pases bien*.

Answer (score 6):

En este caso dices: *Disfruta este regalo*.

Los significados de los dos verbos se solapan (tienen cosas en común), pero si tuviera que traducirlos al inglés diría:

- *Diviértete* = "Have fun!", "Do these things and get pleasure from doing them", "Do these fun things and let yourself be distracted from other things".
- *Disfruta* = "Enjoy!", "Get pleasure from this thing you got or this activity you're doing", "Take advantage of this to enjoy yourself; use this to enjoy yourself".

*Disfrutar* implica consumir, gastar, incorporar, usar. Disfrutas un día en la playa, un regalo, la vida. Es un verbo transitivo, es decir, lleva un objeto directo (opcional), aunque también puede llevar un complemento con la preposición *de*: *Yo disfruto algo.* / *Yo disfruto **de** algo.*

*Divertirse* implica hacer alguna actividad y distraerse. Es un verbo intransitivo, es decir, no lleva objeto directo. *Yo me divierto haciendo algo.* No puedes decir **Diviértete este regalo.* Podrías decir quizá *Diviértete **con** este regalo.* Esto sería si el regalo es algo que se pueda usar, por ejemplo un juego de mesa.

Comment: cuando alguien te gana a poner la respuesta lo único que puedes hacer es darle +1

Comment: Así es... ¡Excelente!